# How can i ngrok edit Forwarding tcp url name and how can i set other name use parameters variables?

Tags: linux, shell, yaml, ngrok

```
ngrok                                                                  (Ctrl+C to quit)

Tunnel Status                 online                                                   
Version                       1.7/1.7                                                  
Forwarding                    tcp://tunnel.123.com:12500 -> 127.0.0.1:22                                           
# Conn                        0                                                       
Avg Conn Time                 0.00ms
```

How can i change tcp://**tunnel**.123.com:12500 -> 127.0.0.1:22 to tcp://**TEST**.123.com:12500 -> 127.0.0.1:22

My config is here

```
server_addr: "123.com:4443"
trust_host_root_certs: false
tunnels:
  ssh:
    proto:
     tcp: 22
    subdomain: TEST
    remote_port: 12500
```